# Multiple NetBIOS names for Windows 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, netbios

I have a shared folder named \\SHARE which is replicated in another server named \\REMOTE

In case of disaster, just change IP address of SHARE in DNS and point it  to REMOTE Server IP, so  i can access \\SHARE and see what is in REMOTE server.

I did it before in windows 2003 and 2008, but i can't do it in Windows 2012 R2.

The steps i follow are:
- Change IP address of SHARE in DNS and point it  to REMOTE Server IP

To configure this in REMOTE server i used to add SHARE name in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanserver\parameters\OptionalNames
But i can't find it in windows 2012R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer myself.

It's exactly same as windows 2003 and 2008 but I didn't find it in regedit at the first time.

1.- Edit the registry key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanserver\parameters
```

2.- add a value **OptionalNames** of type Multi-String. Add in a newline delimited list of names

3.- Reboot Server

Comment: I tried this but it doens't work for me, should it work querying from itself?

Comment: @tobia try adding/setting value `DisableStrictNameChecking` as REG_DWORD to  `1`. See https://dimitri.janczak.net/2016/09/26/multiple-server-names-on-windows/